# Automatic resize of images in HTML5 CSS3 for iPad

Tags: html, webkit, css

I am building a custom app for the iPad and can use webkit specific code. I'm having difficulty with dynamic resizing images to fit within a specific div container. Is there code to do this? Also is the code to recrop an image with a mask if the image is portrait or landscape?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to automatically resize an image with simple CSS:

```
img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

No CSS3 or HTML 5 magic required.  Here's a blog post with more information, and some JavaScript that improves scaling in IE: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/

Comment: I did a little more research and also found this blog. I realized I also need to incorporate the use of background image for what I need to do.